# Bootstrap 3 navbar does't collapse properly in firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

I have created the navigation bar which get collapse once small screens but gives problem in fire fox as shown bellow

[image]

```
<header id="pageHeader">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a> 
      <!-- navbar-collapse -->
      <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-set" > <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-set" >
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Professionals</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
          <form id="header-search" action="search.php" class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for HomeKart">
            </div>
          </form>
          <li><a href="#">My Favourites</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle pull-left" data-toggle="dropdown"> <img src="img/header-profile.png" class="pull-left">Andrews<b class="caret"></b>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Name 1</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Name 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Name 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse --> 
  </nav>
</header>
```

Link: http://play.mink7.com/subitha

Answer (score 2):

This should fix the issue

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation"><div class="container">
  <!-- navbar-collapse -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
  <button  type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar collapse-set" >
 <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
 </button>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
 </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-set" >
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Professionals</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
          <form id="header-search" action="search.php" class="navbar-form navbar-left" style="width:100%;" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for HomeKart">
            </div>
          </form>
          <li><a href="#">My Favourites</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle pull-left" data-toggle="dropdown"> <img src="img/header-profile.png" class="pull-left">Andrews<b class="caret"></b>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Name 1</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Name 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Name 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse --> 
  </nav>
```

Comment: the dropdown starts from the top of the browser where it has to start from below the nav bar. it also gives a scroll bar as i have updated the photo

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question.  Took a closer look a the code.  Updated code above should fix your issue

Comment: trying to figure out what mistake i had done. can you please share it so i can be aware of it

Comment: <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>  is normally inside the button  and your form had no width set  so updated this line with a style="width:100%;  <form id="header-search" action="search.php" class="navbar-form navbar-left" style="width:100%;" role="search">  Please marked as answered if it solved your issue :)

Comment: Take a look here http://getbootstrap.com/components/  default navbar it gives you the skeleton you should build from.